# Get country code from active stores

Tags: magento-1.9, language

I am using this code to display the languages that are active on my magento installation:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang){ ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>">
    <li>
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?>
    </li>
  </a>
<?php } ?>
```

How do I get the country codes to display? I have tried `getId()`, but that only gives me a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code actually displays the name of the stores of your Magento installation**. As you named your stores accordingly to the languages they use you get a list of languages.

**Unfortunately Magento does not link countries and languages out of the box**. Let me rephrase that: Magento does not link stores to countries.

Thus the only thing I can suggest you is to **get the allowed countries based on the store.**

In your `foreach` loop you can add:

```
$countries = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->getResourceCollection()
                                              ->loadByStore($_lang->getStoreId())
                                              ->toOptionArray(true);
```

Comment: That's a shame... well, thanks anyway for helping me understand! :) Ill mark your answer as 'accepted answer', since I won't get closer than this